# What does Siebel Error SBL-BPR-00176 mean?

Tags: jboss, siebel

My webapp talks to Siebel just fine in one test environment, but in another we are getting the following error message:

```
<Exception>
    <Major No.>256</Major No.>
    <Minor No.>6750384</Minor No.>
    <Message>
        The workflow/task engine cannot determine a next step while executing 
        process definition 'Dynamic Pricing Procedure'. The last step that it 
        executed was 'Start'.(SBL-BPR-00176)
    </Message>
    <DetailedMessage>Unknown<DetailedMessage>
</Exception>
```

Any idea about what the error message means and what we might do to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

In short: There is something wrong with your workflow process 'Dynamic Pricing Procedure'

Specifically the conditions (branch of type 'Condition') for the next step (after a decision step) are not setup properly. Can not decide the 'next step' based on conditions setup thus you have SBL-BPR-00176.

You should fix your workflow: Try to do a validation on the workflow process or try to edit the conditional expressions in the Workflow Process Designer.